# How to notify someone from stack community in Q/A

Tags: support, feature-request, notifications

This might be a silly question, but I can't find a solution. Is there a way to notify someone in my answer/question? I know there is a way in comments by writing `@SomeOne`, but I would like to do something similar in an answer.

I have found only this, it is copied from tex.se, since this is the site, where I have the problem (although I hope the solution might be global, if there is a solution).

> **Replying in comments**
>
> The owner of the post you're commenting on will always be notified of your comment. If you are replying to someone else who has previously commented on the same post, mention their username: @peter and @PeterSmith will both notify a previous commenter named “Peter Smith”.
>
> It is generally sufficient to mention only the first name of the user whose comment you are replying to, e.g. @ben or @marc. However you may need to be more specific if three people named Ben replied in earlier comments, by adding the first character of the last name, e.g. @benm or @benc Spaces are not valid in comment reply names, so don't use @peter smith, always enter it as @peters or @petersmith.
>
> If the user you're replying to has no natural first name and last name, simply enter enough characters of the name to make it clear who you are responding to. Three is the minimum, so if you're replying to Fantastico, enter @fan, @fant, or @fantastic.
>
> You can use the same method to notify any editor of the post, or – if this is the case – to the ♦ moderator who closed the question.

But this does not say anything about my problem.

**Question**

- Is there a way to notify someone from stack community in my answer/question?
- If so, how to do it?

**My purpose.**

I have had a question and no one answered it. I have finally find a solution and would like to post it, since others might find that useful. But in my answer I have used something in someone else's answer in different question and I would like them to know I have mentioned them.

**Note**
I have used `feature-request` tag because I do not know if this feature exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such mechanism on answers.

For your purpose - in your answer, add a link to the answer that helped you and some text to point to the fact that you have taken some of that answer (keeping with Stack Exchange attribution requirements).

You can then **comment** on that answer with a link to your answer that was inspired/borrowed from it.

Comment: Is there a reason, why this is not featured? I mean, nobody needed it before or does it go deeper? For instance the protection of the community?

Comment: @quapka - I don't believe anyone thought it was needed. If you want to notify someone who wrote an answer, comments are the mechanism to do so.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, I guess I might as well marked this answer as accepted, since I do not think something too different can appear.

Comment: So, I have decided to link to the answer and also add a link to the profile of the person, who posted the answer. And then notified him in the comment section under his answer.

Comment: If you used an answer, @quapka you should link to it, for attribution.

Comment: I did, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172540/latex-project-together-with-sublime-text-2/173657#173657).